# Share a complex object between processes

Tags: perl, ipc, mojolicious

I want to share a Mojo::Transaction::WebSocket object between processes.

The reason for this is that I am building a websocket chat and I don't want to limit Mojolicious to run only with one worker.

Storable did not work for me it just gives me weird errors.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's various ways you can achieve, this. To share the websocket itself would be hard, and requires a solid understanding of process forking/threading, sharing file descriptors, and knowledge of the mojolicious foundation code, which very likely will need to be changed.

If your aim is to load balance, or perform some long running task, your better off having your mojo application take the request, and add it to a queue system such as redis. You can have multiple processes listening for specific requests, read the payload, and send a response back through the queue.

If you just want to be able to access the internals of your Mojo application for other purposes, consider proving a restful endpoint with the data you wish to publish,

Alternatively, you can look at remote procedure calls (RPC) which will allow your Mojo process to call functions, and send data to other processes. Look at [RPC::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~cedwards/RPC-Simple-1.002/Simple.pm) as an example.